# How to make Prettier, Eslint and Visual Studio Code play nice together

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm having problems getting prettier, eslint and visual studio code play nice together. I keep seeing red errors such as this in VSCode:

```
[eslint] Replace `↹` with `··` (prettier/prettier)
```

I have VSCode plugins eslint and prettier installed.

VSCode config

`{
  "javascript.validate.enable": false,
  "javascript.format.enable": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "prettier.singleQuote": true,
  "prettier.eslintIntegration": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": -1,
  "editor.fontSize": 13
}`

.eslintrc

```
    {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
        "airbnb",
        "plugin:react-native/all",
        "prettier",
        "prettier/react",
        "prettier/standard"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "jest": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "expect": true,
        "sinon": true,
        "Promise": true,
        "__DEV__": true
    },
    "plugins": ["babel", "react", "react-native", "prettier"],
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
            "paths": ["app"]
        }
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
        "indent": [2, "tab", { "SwitchCase": 1 }],
        "comma-dangle": [2, "only-multiline"],
        "react/jsx-indent": [0, "tab"],
        "jsx-quotes": [2, "prefer-double"],
        "react/display-name": 0,
        "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-undef": 2,
        "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 0,
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 0,
        "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 2, // [2, "allow-in-func"],
        "react/no-did-update-set-state": 2,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 0,
        "react/no-unknown-property": 2,
        "react/prop-types": 1,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 2,
        "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
        "react/sort-comp": 2,
        "react/jsx-wrap-multilines": 2,
        "react-native/no-color-literals": 1,
        "quotes": [
        2,
        "single",
        "avoid-escape"
        ]
    }
    }
```

dev dependencies package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "3.0.0-beta.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.8.0",
    "chai-immutable": "^1.6.0",
    "commitizen": "^2.9.6",
    "cz-conventional-changelog": "^2.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint": "^4.7.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "expect.js": "^0.3.1",
    "flow": "^0.2.3",
    "flow-bin": "^0.56.0",
    "immutablediff": "^0.4.3",
    "jest": "^21.2.1",
    "jshint": "^2.9.5",
    "mocha": "^3.4.2",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-intl-cra": "^0.2.8",
    "react-native-mock": "^0.3.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "redux-debounce": "^1.0.1",
    "redux-debounced": "^0.4.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.11.0",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.12",
    "sinon": "^4.0.0"
}
```

Comment: I'm interested in this as well... Currently I'm using Vetur extension (for Vue.js) and this extension uses prettier... so the .vue files on formatting removes spaces, and extra semicolons, replaces the double quotes with single... which is really nice, but the problem is with .js extensions; I don't know how to make them work the same. So if you managed to find, please share.

Comment: have you managed to find a fix for this?

Comment: Please refer to the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215590/prettier-vscode-eslint-weird-format-syntax-breaking-bug?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prettier/VSCode Eslint weird format/syntax breaking bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215590/prettier-vscode-eslint-weird-format-syntax-breaking-bug)

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to modify the Visual Studio Code settings to format files when saving ["editor.formatOnSave": true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYRNs.png) and run ESLint when saving files ["eslint.run": "onSave"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x8IP.png). You can find a more detailed explanation at [Prettier Formatter for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `eslint-config-prettier` package and in your eslint config file add `prettier` to the `extends` array

```js
{
  extends: ['prettier']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run lint -- --fix
```

It's ok for me but you have to deactivate the `Prettier` extension to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

When I used this part into `.eslintrc` file, that works for my code.

```json
"extends": [
    "plugin:react/essential",
],
```

Comment: not relevaant to the post

Answer (score -3):

Solved using fix

```
yarn run lint --fix
```

Answer (score -3):

Had the same issue.

```
{
  "useTabs": false
}
```

This fixed my issue