# Visual Studio code error while saving react files special app.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTBXv.png)I also face this type problem in app.js, so kindly what should I do it for ?
[And Showing error as:

JSX element div has no corresponding closing tag.
JSX element Navbar has no corresponding closing tag.
JSX element NavbarBrand has no corresponding closing tag.
Identifier expected.

> expected.]

Comment: Please provide more information, such as part of the code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53115881/visual-studio-code-error-while-saving-react-files

Comment: the code will be look like this image if i change the extension they create the error like this .

Comment: Somehow you've "prettified" your code and it's made a bit of a mess. All those red lines you can see are VSCode telling you something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have a view issue regarding your IDE.

In the bottom right, you will see that you are in JavaScript.

2 solutions:

- You can right click and change to React
  or
- You can change the extension file by .JSX

After that it should work.